# How to provide a external API/URL to spring boot & angular app?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

- We have an web app with spring boot as backend and angular 5 as it's front end. Let's name this web app as Web-App 1.
- We have another web app say Web-App 2 which contains a link. On click of the link, it will create an iframe and open Web-App 1 inside that iframe.
- Web-App 1 has to provide an link which will be used in web-app 2. Web-App-2 triggers this link as post request and sends authentication data(authToken) as post parameters which will be used by web-app-1.
- Now the issue is what kind of link does web-app 1 need to provide to web-app We can't provide index.html of angular app since we can't read post parameters on client side.
- If we provide an rest api, we can read those authentication information but then how do we tranfer authToken to client side ?
- The solution that I have tried is writing an JSP which will be provided as link to Web-App 2. In that jsp, I will retrieve post parameters and assign it to javascript variables which will be then accessed in angular app.
- This solution work's because we have used this technique in other apps as well, I am just trying to find a way to avoid using JSP's.

Comment: My suggestion is that you let the request be handled by web-app 1 itself. Just provide a link to the Web-app 1 url that you want to hit and also while redirecting append the auth token as header. This way when the request reaches the Web-App1, it can authenticate the user using the auth token taken from the header and serve the request, you can add some kind of interceptor or something in the web-app to extract the token from the header and authenticate if needed . Also,enable CORS on both web-apps.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan - Thanks for response. Authentication for me is not a problem. The request will be authenticated by web-app 1 interceptor. The issue is if the request is handled at server, how do I transfer that authToken to client ? I need that authToken on client side so that I can add that authToken in subsequent calls.

Comment: You can handle that using the javascript, for example once the user leaves the login screen, the auth token will be returned in the response header right.So, you can have a jquery or angular global setting which will take this token and add this to a global header so that for every request made from the client side this token will be present in the header.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan Let me explain the entire flow. Web App 2 opens web app 1 inside iframe. Web App 2 sends authToken to Web app 1. Web app 1 doesn't have to worry about authentication, it just need to have that authToken available on client side, so that it can pass it on every request to rest api of web app 1. Now how do I get that authToken on client side, since the first call to web app 1 was a post request on index.html ?

Comment: Which is the first call invoked from client-side and to which one(Web2 OR web1) ?

Comment: @DEBENDRADHINDA - User will log in to Web App 2 and then open Web App 1 by invoking a URL provided by Web App 1 and by passing authToken as post parameter. I am thinking what should that URL that need to provided to Web App 2, should it be some JSP or servlet or directly angular index.html.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Flow diagram]

If this is your flow diagram, angular is the very best option.

In WebApp2, after authentication, it should return a response which might contain the WebApp1 URL and the AuthToken. i.e. the login page which has invoked the login request, it has the response now .E.g. Ajax call. From that response, you can retrieve the auth token and attach as a header to the webapp1 URL. i.e. you have already the auth token in your client-side......

If Webapp2 redirects, then you can set the token in response header too
Otherwise.....
Expose an API URL from WEBAPP2 which will generate the token and will return to the page. You can use it....

Comment: Debendra this won't work. Web App 2 has its own functionality. Once you login in to Web app 2, users will perform some functions and if they wish to go to Web App 1, then there will be a menu on click of which Web App 1 will be opened. Web App 1 is not going to be opened immediately after login.

Comment: That's fine that means you have an option to track the authentication token after successful authentication from web2 because the  navigation menu is present on webpp2 which can provide the authentication token and that you can keep on client side on success call of ajax and you can use it for request. that means you can pass that authentication talking to any request by setting the header for the ajax call and you can use it